# GitHub API error "rate limit exceeded" How to increase

Tags: git, rest, api, powershell, limit

I am requesting github more with REST requests and after 60-th request I got error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"API rate limit exceeded for
>   211.24.122.123. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more
>   details.)","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"}

I know about rate limit and have checked docs by the link above.
Added to my request `?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy` but it still doesn't work

Could you give an example of request for increasing the rate? Please

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting these type of questions.

Comment: You did change `xxxx` to YOUR client ID and `yyyy` to YOUR personal token I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You're not making an authenticated requests, you will need to create a PAT and call with the header `Authentication: Bearer $TOKEN`, which will give you a much more reasonable throttle.

Comment: How long will it take until the rate is reset?

Comment: The API response will give you headers which tell you exactly how long, you can use them to wait. It will also give you the number of call available in your throttle window so you use that to limit yourself. The limits are per minute but if you exceed you coudl be looking at a several minute delay. Read the docs carefully for details!

Comment: Yeah I figured `curl -L https://api.github.com/rate_limit` was helpful, and epochconverter.com to read the reset timestamp.